# Docker Windows container running DLL's

Tags: docker

I work at a lab and we have some devices that use DLL’s to connect to our computers and exchange data, I’m building a docker container from which we will run experiments and communicate with many different devices, most of them use python libraries or a DAQ (that can also be used from python), but some use DLL’s.
My questions are:

Can I have Linux running on my machine and have Windows as the container’s OS?

Will I be able to connect using the DLL’s with this setup?

Will I be able to use the DLL’s if my machine does not run Windows 10 PRO (we use 
win8 home and plan to upgrade to win10 home)?

Can I use these DLL’s from inside the container? Do they need to be in the container?

Answer (score 1):

1.- Docker has two host container types, windows and linux, only windows host type (windows machine) can run windows containers and linux containers, because you can run **net framework** in windows containers, and linux host only run linux containers.

2.- If you dll use cross platform [**net core**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/), you can run in both docker hosts linux and windows, but you has libraries that use net framework , you can use windows host container, you can migrate to net core  via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) ,i made in c#

3.- Even you has enable in bios processor option and your machine has hardware requirements, you can use docker, find more [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)

4.- I recommend use a existent official image, only you need add your code  , you can find [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core) and check samples

Comment: how to I know if my DLL is net core?

Comment: you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160722/using-precompiled-net-assembly-dll-in-mono