# How to refer to DLL files on a Linux Container?

Tags: c#, windows, kubernetes, dll, amazon-eks

I have an `App` which I am developing, it uses an external `SDK` that has a number of `DLLs` which need to be referred from my application code. Because of this reason, I have to explore ways to deploy this app on a `windows` container in `EKS`, but I would like to have a better way to refer to these `DLL`s in some externalized way or decoupled from my `linux` container only, so that I do not need to create a windows container only for that purpose. I tried to go through some links as well as below to figure that out, but couldn't get a clear picture.

[Docker Windows container running DLL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265433/docker-windows-container-running-dlls)

[Using Windows DLL from Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374157/using-windows-dll-from-linux)

[Using Precompiled .NET Assembly DLL in Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160722/using-precompiled-net-assembly-dll-in-mono)

Is that possible in any manner or will I have to use a windows container only just because my code refers to some `DLL`s while performing backend operations?

Comment: It depends on the type of the DLL. If they are DLLs compiled with .NET Core or .NET 5 you most likely can just use them under Linux. -> We need more details

Comment: Daniel , thanks for the comment . Can you let me a easy way to find out whether a DLL is compiled with .NET core or .NET 5 ?

Comment: You could try opening it in IL Spy. If it works, it's .NET. The exact type and version should be visible somewhere as well