# How do I test if my DLL will run in Linux

Tags: .net, windows, mono

I need to test if some of the DLLs that I use will run in .NET core or mono, basically to see if we can run it in Linux, i saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160722/using-precompiled-net-assembly-dll-in-mono) talking about Mono but I don't know how to use it to test my DLL.

Comment: Find a Linux machine, install Mono and then test your library. SO is not a site for tutorials.

Comment: I suggest using something like Vagrant and VirtualBox to set yourself up a linux VM on your local machine, assuming you are using Windows. Install Mono on it, copy over your executable, as see if it runs.

Comment: what shoud expect to see if it doesn't run in linux?

Comment: @Nillmer Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find it.